# Duration datetime (djangorest , json input)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying of finding a way to make a "duration" variable, which will hold a datetime that will show if the auction of my app is over or still going.
I got a "created" variable which shows the time that the auction was created, i need to find a way to create a "duration" variable so i can validate the state of the item (if it's still active or not).
Not only do i need a field suggestion, i also need a way to pass json data from frontend (reactjs) to my backend (django-rest) via my serializer.

I 've tried to serialize with DateTimeField, DurationField, even thought of using IntegerField (total minutes) and then converting them to days/hours/min but still the solution is not clear in my head.

`created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now=True) #is my datetime that the model was created`

`duration = ? #i need a way to pass json data to this field and create a valid datetime instance`

json data{?}

i am expecting a valid duration (datetime)field, created with the data that the user provides via post method.

Comment: You can take a `DateTimeField` as auction `end_date` and then in your serializer use annotation to calculate the remaining duration of the auction from current date. duration = (end_date - current_date).

Comment: the thing is that i am trying to think of a way to get user input (days, hours, mins) and then convert that to currentDate += {userDurationInput}.
 For example if the current time is :datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 29, 23, 15, 21, 353652). I want to figure out a way to add the users "userDurationInput" to this format and then having my "duration.DateTimeField" to do my later comparisons. Maybe this would work : datetime.now() + timedelta(days=100, hours = 5) ?

Comment: Sure you can do that, whats the problem you are facing in accomplishing this task.

Comment: i was trying to think of a way, to pass the {days,hours,minutes} ,from my reactjs frontend to my djangorest backend, using my serializer's "duration" DateTimeField. And THEN do <perform_create(self, serializer):> to save the datetime.now() += timedelta(days, hours,minutes). My question is : should i try to use my duration DateTimeField directly , or maybe i could pass the {days,hours,minutes} data via extra fields (context) to my backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. So what i did was :

in the front-end (reactJs) i created a
`duration = Date();` 
then i modified my date object :

`duration .setDate(date.getDate() + <numberOfDays> );` //to add days duration

then used

`duration .toISOString();`
 `duration .toJSON();`

to format my DateTime. Then i called my post method and saved that in the 
backend django-rest field :
`duration = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)`